# mariadb / mysql se cae cada menos de 24 horas. aqui el registro de lo que aparece

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

como dice el título, mi mysql/mariadb se cae cada menos de 24 horas. la verdad ya no sé que podría ser, he hecho casi de todo y no logro solucionar el problema.

dejo el registro de las últimas líneas que aparece en el log de errores antes de caerse y tener que reiniciarlo. (cuando reinicio ya levanta normal por unas horas nuevamente)

```
211122 15:12:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
211122 15:12:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
211122 15:12:48 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 2147483648 adjusted to 1073741824
211122 15:12:48 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
211122 15:12:48 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.68-MariaDB) starting as process 30979 ...
211122 15:12:48 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
211122 15:12:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
211122 15:12:48  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
211122 15:12:49 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 10484703095
211122 15:12:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
211122 15:12:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
211122 15:12:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
211122 15:12:49 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
211122 15:13:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
211122 15:13:33 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
211122 15:13:33  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
211122 15:13:38  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 10484713901
211122 15:13:38 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

211122 15:13:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
211122 15:13:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
211122 15:13:39 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 2147483648 adjusted to 1073741824
211122 15:13:39 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
211122 15:13:39 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.68-MariaDB) starting as process 31515 ...
211122 15:13:39 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 65535  max_connections: 64725  table_cache: 400
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
211122 15:13:39 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
211122 15:13:39  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
211122 15:13:40 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 10484713901
211122 15:13:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
211122 15:13:40 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
211122 15:13:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
211122 15:13:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.68-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

La verdad ya tengo días con este problema, dejo mi my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 20480M
max_allowed_packet = 20480M
table_open_cache = 2560
sort_buffer_size = 1000M
read_buffer_size = 1000M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 40M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 10240M
thread_cache_size = 1000
query_cache_size= 20480M
thread_concurrency = 8

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table=1

#MODIFICADO IN
join_buffer_size=2048M
table_definition_cache=32768
table_open_cache=32768

#MODIFICADO OUT


max_connections=100000
max_user_connections=50000
wait_timeout=10000
interactive_timeout=5000
long_query_time=100

#slow_query_log=1
#slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

tenga en cuenta que los valores por defecto los tuve que modificar porque con los que tenía también se estaba cayendo el mysql.

la verdad no sé que podría estar sucediendo. ¿alguien interpreta mejor el log de errores?
¿alguna ayuda sugerencia?

Comment: Tienes algunas configuraciones que sobrepasan los límites permitidos, como `max_allowed_packet` y `max_connections`, además de una obsoleta. Tengo la impresión de que no manejas correctamente las conexiones y por eso incrementaste esa variable; de ser así, el problema no es el motor de base de datos, sino la forma en que lo estás usando. Revisa primero si puedes optimizar la programación para evitar esas caídas.

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, ¿cual variable esta obsoleta? y cual deberia ser los valores para una gran cantidad de trafico en max_connections y max_allowed_packet ?

Comment: De acuerdo al log `[Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated...`. Insisto, antes de modificar esos valores, que el mismo log te dice que los ajustó, debes buscar el origen del problema, no siempre es la cantidad de tráfico.

Comment: el sitio ya estaba trabajando en otro servidor y funcionaba correctamente, cuando se migró a un nuevo servidor con menos de la mitad de los recursos que tenía el servidor anterior fue cuando inicio el problema. (por eso asumí desde el primer momento que tenía que ver con recursos por eso).

Comment: En este momento (y para resolver momentáneamente el problema), lo que hice fue crear una tarea cron, que cada 12 horas se ejecute y reinicie el servicio de mariadb. ya que este es el causante del conflicto. sin embargo, sé que esta no es una solución real al problema. ¿alguna otra sugerencia?